# Jackson - Bidirectional - Deserialization Parent Id

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jackson

I'm having trouble to populate an entity with a json file when I have a bidirectional relationship.

**Parent class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = ".....")
public class CpoPipeline implements... {

    private String pipelineId;
    private String pipelineSource;
    private String pipelineVersion;
    private Set<CpoPipelineParameter> cpoPipelineParameters;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "cpoPipeline")
    public Set<CpoPipelineParameter> getCpoPipelineParameters() {
        return this.cpoPipelineParameters;
    }
```

**Child class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = ".....")
public class CpoPipelineParameter implements ...{

    private String pipelineParameterId;
    private CpoPipeline cpoPipeline;
    private String pipelineParameterName;
    private String pipelineParameterValue;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "pipeline_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    public CpoPipeline getCpoPipeline() {
        return this.cpoPipeline;
    }
```

**Json:**

```
{
    "cpoPipeline": {
    "pipelineId": "1",
    "pipelineSource": "C://",
    "pipelineVersion": "2.0",
    "cpoPipelineParameters": [
        {
        "pipelineParameterId": "2",
        "pipelineParameterName": "Process_Group_Variable_Year",
        "pipelineParameterValue": "2020"
        },
        {
        "pipelineParameterId": "1",
        "pipelineParameterName": "Process_Group_Variable_Directory",
        "pipelineParameterValue": "C://"
        }
    ]
    }
}
```

When I try to populate the entity with the json file, the parent id is not going into the child entity. 
So when I try to persist I'm getting the error:

> 17:26:54.714 [main] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - NULL not allowed for column "PIPELINE_ID"; 
>   SQL statement:insert into cpo_pipeline_parameter (pipeline_id, pipeline_parameter_name, pipeline_parameter_value, pipeline_parameter_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)

Comment: Missing `CascadeType.ALL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `CpoPipeline` for every `CpoPipelineParameter`. In bidirectional relation if you want to save parent with child, then you have to set the parent for each child to make both side sync.

```
cpoPipeline.getCpoPipelineParameters().forEach(d -> d.setCpoPipeline(cpoPipeline));
```

Comment: Is there no way to do this automatically, with annotations or something? Bacause this is just one piece of my json file, but in real I'm importing a big json file.

Comment: Nope. You have to sync both sides and this operation is not very costly.
Many people face the same problem, have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61293079/spring-boot-hibernate-onetomany-foreign-key#comment108431350_61293079

Comment: did you try this solution ?

Comment: This solution will work but I'm trying a better solution because I'm doing a process of export and import by json file and, as I said, I have a big json file with 30 tables to make this forEach @Abinash.

Comment: @AldoInáciodaSilva As far I know there is no better solution. If you found any must tell me.